# Iterator not working for my Queue?

Tags: java, timer, iterator, queue, nodes

So right now I am making a store simulator, that calculates thing such as items, average wait time for a customer in line, etc. So far I have been able to get all of the required data no problem, but now I am having trouble setting a timer for each customer that is not currently being checked out. So if a customer in the queue is not first (being the one checked out) I start a timer that increments their wait time by one every second. Once they become the first (they get to be checked out) it stops their timer, and then adds that time to the overall waiting time of that line, or queue. The way I am doing it is every second the program will run this method with each Queue (in this case I have six "lines" or queues). Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
    private void waitTime(LineQueue<Customer> l){
    Iterator<Customer> iter = l.iterator();
    Customer[] c = new Customer[l.size()]; 
    int count = 0;

    if(iter.hasNext()){
        try{
            c[count] = iter.next(); 
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            //does nothing with it
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; 1 < c.length; i++){
        try{
            c[i].incrimentWaitTime();
        }catch(NullPointerException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            //does nothing with it
        }
    }
}
```

and then how it is implemented:

```
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                for(LineQueue<Customer> e : queues){
                    waitTime(e);
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

At this point I am not sure what to do, although from how I see it I have to use an Iterator to make this properly work. Also here is the code for how every thing is put into the queue:

```
    private static class Node<Customer> {
    private Customer data;
    private Node<Customer> next;

    private Node(Customer dataItem) {
        data = dataItem;
        next = null;
    }
    private Node(Customer dataItem, Node<Customer> nodeRef){
        data = dataItem;
        next = nodeRef;
    }
}

private Node<Customer> front;
private Node<Customer> rear;
private Node<Customer> ref;

public boolean offers(Customer e){
    if(size == 0){
        front = new Node<Customer>(e);
    }else if(size == 1){
        front.next = new Node<Customer>(e);
        ref = front.next;
    }else{
        ref.next = new Node<Customer>(e);
        ref = ref.next;
    }
    size++;
    CPH++;
    return true;
}
```

Here is the inner Iterator class:

```
    private class Iter implements Iterator<Customer>{
    private int count;
    private Node<Customer> obj;

    public Iter(){
        obj = front;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext(){
        return count < size;
    }

    @Override
    public Customer next(){
        if(!hasNext()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        Customer returnVal = obj.next.data;
        obj = obj.next;
        count++;
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Hopefully that should be enough to understand what is going on.

Comment: Lots of code, but what is the problem? Why do you implement your own Queue class instead of using a standard collection (like LinkedList)?

Comment: I need to use a Queue, and not a standard LinkedList. The problem I am having trouble iterating over the queue(s), so I am can increment to timer I talked about.

Comment: A LinkedList **is** a Queue. Saying "it doesn't work" or "I'm having trouble" doesn't help. Describe the problem precisely. What do you do, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: @JB Nizet I explained that in my description. I need to be able to iterate of a queue, get the Customer object from the queue, and increment its timer by one every second.

Comment: Off topic, but why increment the timer every second?  Why not take a timestamp when they enter the queue, another when they get to the head and add the difference to the queue's running total?

Comment: That's not a problem, that's a requirement. I need to go to the supermarket is a requirement. I broke my leg by slipping on a banana while going to the supermarket is a problem: I expected to go to the supermarket and come back, and instead slipped, took an ambulance and went to the hospital. Start by removing the catch blocks that do nothing except hiding exceptions, and thus make problems invisible.

Comment: @adamdc78 I guess I could do it that way, that might be more efficient. I will try that.

Comment: @JV Nizet, I originally started off with no try-catch blocks. I added them in so I could see how to program would run without the errors.

Comment: So, there were errors, and you chose to ignore them, hoping it would magically work? That's never, ever going to work. If you get an exception, you look at its stack trace, understand its cause, and fix the code. That's the problem you should have had in your post: "the code throws an exception, here is its stack trace." As simple as that.

Comment: @JB Nizet it threw both errors I am ignoring, in the method for incrementing. I can recreate them, and post them if you would like.

Comment: @adamdc78 that works, thank you!

Comment: As in it solved your iteration problem or it's more efficient?

Comment: @adamdc78 did not solve the iteration issue, but it gave me another way to do it. Not using the iteration now.